# RMI: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to Funktion

Tags: java, generics, interface, rmi, classcastexception

im working on a differentiator which is working. Now i want it to be remote aswell.
So i have a "Function"-Interface, a "Funktion"-class implementing the Function interface.
Then i have a Server, a client and a generic service interface. Part of the code:

```
public class DifferentiatorClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, IllegalArgumentException, NotBoundException, RecognitionException {
    execute();
}

public static Double execute() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, IllegalArgumentException, RecognitionException {
    Service<Funktion, Double, Double> service;
    String url = "//localhost/DifferentiatorService";
    Double r;
    Script script = new Script();
    Funktion f = script.getFunction("f");
    service = (Service<Funktion, Double, Double>) Naming.lookup(url);
    r = service.execute(f, 2.0);
    return r;

}

}
```

The class "Funktion":

```
public class Funktion extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Function, Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1234132759512350836L;
//some methods
}
```

The interface "Function":

```
public interface Function  extends java.rmi.Remote {

double eval(final double ... args) throws IllegalArgumentException, RecognitionException, RemoteException;
}
```

The server:

```
public class DifferentiatorService extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject
    implements Service<Funktion, Double, Double> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3236697150408344006L;

protected DifferentiatorService() throws RemoteException {

}

@Override
public String getName() throws RemoteException {
    return "DifferentiatorService";

}

public Double execute(Funktion f, Double... args) throws RemoteException {
    Differentiator diff = new Differentiator();
    double result = diff.differentiate(f, args[0]);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "//localhost/DifferentiatorService";
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    DifferentiatorService service = new DifferentiatorService();
    Naming.rebind(url, service);
}

}
```

And last, the service interface:

```
public interface Service<T,A,R> extends java.rmi.Remote {

String getName() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;

R execute(T task,A ... args) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

Sorry for this wall of code, i just think it might be necessary to find the error.
First of all, if i use a service like:

`Service<String, Double, Double> service;`
and then parse the String on the "server-side" and returning the result its working perfectly.
The cast: `service = (Service<String, Double, Double>) Naming.lookup(url);` doesnt make any problems then.

However im trying to make it work with Funktion objects. I always get the exception from the title.
I googled alot and people where saying its important to cast to an interface and not to an concrete class.
I think i am casting to an interface with

```
service = (Service<Funktion, Double, Double>) Naming.lookup(url);
```

I also tried:

```
service = (Service<Function, Double, Double>) Naming.lookup(url);
```

but getting the same exception.

I hope someone can help me.
Best regards

## Edit: Working with the interface "Function" in client and server results in this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:229)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.execute(Unknown Source)
    at de.lab4inf.wrb.DifferentiatorClient.execute(DifferentiatorClient.java:25)
    at de.lab4inf.wrb.DifferentiatorClient.main(DifferentiatorClient.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:215)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Your code says `class DifferentiatorService` ... `implements Service<Funktion**en**, Double, Double>`. Have you tried casting to that exact interface type, or is Funktion**en** a typo?

Comment: Ah sorry, i renamed the class Funktionen to Funktion, since the name was kinda bad. Its all the same class. Just edited it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but are you sure the exception happens on the `Naming.lookup`? I am asking because during the `service.execute` RMI might need to cast a remote proxy (on the server for the client's `f`) as the first argument of `DifferentiatorService.execute(Funktion...)` which is again a class, not an interface (`Function`?).

Comment: Yea you are right. To be honest i am a little bit confused where i can use concret classes and where i need to use interfaces. If i change all the "Funktion" into "Function"(so the interface) in the server AND the client i get an "Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException". If i just change it in the client i get the error from the title, so nothing rly changes. Maybe you can tell me where i need concrete classes and where i need interfaces. Im new to RMI and these stubs etc rly confuse me. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: I am no RMI expert but you use interfaces for all RemoteObjects (which get passed by reference) because RMI uses proxies for remote callers, and proxies are only for interfaces. In your case, a client obj is passed to the server by ref (RemoteObject!) and the server just sees a proxy from RMI which it then uses to call back the client. BTW: The exception you get might indicate that client and server do not currently use the same version of some value class and deserialization misses data. All classes (potentially) passed by value (non-RemoteObjects) between client and server should be in sync.

Comment: Server and client are in the same package, so they should be synced. So as far as i understand i need to use the interface in the client. So: `Service<Function, Double, Double> service;` Just wondering if i have to work with the interface or the concrete class on the server side. Guess the interface aswell? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please post the stack trace and indicate the relevant source lines.

Comment: Allright, since i have only ~600 characters ill just post a picture of the exception. Hope thats allright: 
[link](http://i.epvpimg.com/KcJ4f.png)
Line25 in die DifferentiatorClient is: `r = service.execute(f, 2.0);`  In renamed Funktion to FunctionImpl. So in the client and in the server im working only with the interface "Function" now. When i start the client again, after the exception from first picture i get this one: ` java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. Probably cause sth crashed before

Comment: No, post the exception. Edit it into your question. I'm not chasing links for information that should have been posted in the question in the first place. And don't post code or exceptions in commwnts. You can see for yourself that they are completely illegible. If changing to `Function` has fixed the class cast problem you should accept or upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast the stub to the implementation class `Funktion`. It isn't an instance of that class. It's an instance of the remote interface. So, cast it to the remote interface: `Function`. And change the signatures throughout the `Service` class accordingly.

NB You're asking for trouble keeping these names so similar. Change the first to `FunctionImpl`, `FunctionServer`, `FunctionRemoteObject`, or whatever.